# Errors when installing jdk 1.7 in linux

Tags: linux, installation, java, jdk

When I am installing jdk 1.7 in Oracle Linux by using the following

rpm -ivh jdk-7u9-linux-i586.rpm

However I am getting the following errors, how can I resolve these errors and install jdk 1.7?

Any help is highly appreciable.

Thanks

```
rpm -ivh /tmp/mnt/jdk-7u9-linux-i586.rpm
Preparing...                ########################################### [100%]
   1:jdk                    ########################################### [100%]
Unpacking JAR files...
        rt.jar...
Error: Could not open input file: /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_09/jre/lib/rt.pack
        jsse.jar...
Error: Could not open input file: /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_09/jre/lib/jsse.pack
        charsets.jar...
Error: Could not open input file: /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_09/jre/lib/charsets.pack
        tools.jar...
Error: Could not open input file: /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_09/lib/tools.pack
        localedata.jar...
Error: Could not open input file: /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_09/jre/lib/ext/localedata.pack
        plugin.jar...
Error: Could not open input file: /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_09/jre/lib/plugin.pack
        javaws.jar...
Error: Could not open input file: /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_09/jre/lib/javaws.pack
        deploy.jar...
Error: Could not open input file: /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_09/jre/lib/deploy.pack
```

My Linux version is  `oracle linux 5.5`

Comment: 1.requires root access.2.I hope rpm you downloaded isnt corrupt!!

Comment: @swapyonubuntu I did that as root. Not sure whether rpm was corrupt or not. But installation I did a reboot and when I typed java -version it showed correct version. Thanks